# Record from the database by ID in the ASP.NET MVC project on the main page of the site

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to take an entry from the database by ID in the ASP.NET MVC project on the main page of the site, that is, in the Home-Index folder, but I don't know how, I tried this, but nothing worked. Please tell me how this can be done?

```
enter code here



 <div class="offer">
        <div class="offer__header">
            <h2 class="offer__title">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name_vouchers, new {id=5})
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="offer__body">
            <div class="offer__body-img">
                <img src="~/Content/image/Vouchers/@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.image, new {id=5})" />
            </div>
            <div class="offer__body-content">
                <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Route.Country.Name_country, new {id=5})<br>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Departure_date, new {id=5}) <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Date_arrival, new {id=5})<br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cost, new {id=5})<br>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Information_vouchers, new {id=5})
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Excursions, new {id=5})
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offer__body-footer">
            <button class="button bron">Viewing</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the code of the controller:

enter code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BigTravel_Company.Models;

namespace BigTravel_Company.Controllers
{
    public class VouchersController : Controller
    {
        private BigTravelEntities db = new BigTravelEntities();

        // GET: Vouchers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var vouchers = db.Vouchers.Include(v => v.hotel).Include(v => v.Route);
            return View(vouchers.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Index(int id = 5)
        {
            var model = db.(id);
            return View(model);
        }
        // GET: Vouchers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Vouchers vouchers = db.Vouchers.Find(id);
            if (vouchers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vouchers);
        }

        // GET: Vouchers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.id_hotel = new SelectList(db.hotel, "id_hotel", "Namehotel");
            ViewBag.id_route = new SelectList(db.Route, "id_route", "Place");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id_vouchers,name_vouchers,id_route,id_hotel,Departure_date,Date_arrival,Information_vouchers,Excursions,image,Cost,number_trips")] Vouchers vouchers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Vouchers.Add(vouchers);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.id_hotel = new SelectList(db.hotel, "id_hotel", "Namehotel", vouchers.id_hotel);
            ViewBag.id_route = new SelectList(db.Route, "id_route", "Place", vouchers.id_route);
            return View(vouchers);
        }

     
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Vouchers vouchers = db.Vouchers.Find(id);
            if (vouchers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.id_hotel = new SelectList(db.hotel, "id_hotel", "Namehotel", vouchers.id_hotel);
            ViewBag.id_route = new SelectList(db.Route, "id_route", "Place", vouchers.id_route);
            return View(vouchers);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id_vouchers,name_vouchers,id_route,id_hotel,Departure_date,Date_arrival,Information_vouchers,Excursions,image,Cost,number_trips")] Vouchers vouchers)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(vouchers).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.id_hotel = new SelectList(db.hotel, "id_hotel", "Namehotel", vouchers.id_hotel);
            ViewBag.id_route = new SelectList(db.Route, "id_route", "Place", vouchers.id_route);
            return View(vouchers);
        }

        // GET: Vouchers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Vouchers vouchers = db.Vouchers.Find(id);
            if (vouchers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(vouchers);
        }

        // POST: Vouchers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Vouchers vouchers = db.Vouchers.Find(id);
            db.Vouchers.Remove(vouchers);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

And here I do not understand what you need to write, please tell me?

```
 enter code here

public ActionResult Index(int id = 5)
        {
            var model = db.(id);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: I don't know how your project works but you can use id as **hidden**  in model binding. This usage is like that **@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)** .No need to add new { id=5} to displayfor elements. If you use model binding, hidden id will be useful.

Comment: @GökhanAldanmaz, Hello, do you mean to write it down like this?   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id_vouchers == 5)

Answer (score 0):

MVC pattern means: model, view and controller.
Controller manupulating data, and load it's into model.
Then model transmit into 'view' to display and change by user. And back.

So, you must load data from database into model in controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int id = 5)
    {
        var model = database.loadById(id);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

database.loadById - this is your implementation of model load

When you enter on page without any defined 'id' - you will see data from default id value.
So, if you request .../Home/index/8 - you will see object with id = 8.

Then, in view, you define in top of code page

```
@model <namespace containing model class>.ModelClass
```

And then you can use your code to display loaded model, as you show in your post.

Unfortunately, you show us only piece of view code. But you not show your model and controller to answer mo exact about your problem.

More about model in MVC you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Hello, here is such a controller I have, I do not quite understand what you mean by the implementation of loading the model :-(

Comment: How do you get data from database? If you don't know - first you must read about Entity Framework. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it in controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Display(int id = 0)
    {

        var data= new model()
        {
            
            ModelList= db.Model.Where(b => b.id== id).ToList(),

            ModelData= db.modellist.FirstOrDefault(b => b.id== id)

        };
        return View("Display", data);

        
    }
```

and pass id from mvc view using

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display", "Display", new { id = item.id}, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "edit" }) |
```

Comment: Hello, but if I do not need to use the link, then how can I do it?

Comment: you can pass the id using ajax on button click

Comment: $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

        var data = {

            id: $("#id").val(),

            toDate: $("#toDate").val(),

            fromDate: $("#fromDate").val()
        }

        $.ajax({

            type: "post",

            url: "/ControllerName/MethodnameInController",

            data: data,

            datatype: "json",

            cache: false,
            }
        });

    });

Comment: @АвгустКук Hello if you this helpful then can you mark it as helps as answer